# Google urlshortener api showing 403 error

Tags: google-api, url-shortener, google-url-shortener

before its working fine

```
https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

but current now showing error

```
{

  "error": {
   "errors": [
    {
     "domain": "global",
     "reason": "forbidden",
     "message": "Forbidden"
    }
   ],
   "code": 403,
   "message": "Forbidden"
  }
 }
```

what i have to do ?

Answer (score 1):

Google is in the process of shutting down URL shortner.  I think you should start looking for another option

[Transitioning Google URL Shortener to Firebase Dynamic Links](https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/transitioning-google-url-shortener.html)

> Starting May 30, 2018, only projects that have accessed URL Shortener APIs before today can create short links. To create new short links, we recommend FDL APIs. FDL short links will automatically detect the user's platform and send the user to either the web or your app, as appropriate.